# How to log method calls with parameters in a built application?

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I have a rather old .net remoting c# client app, and I need to figure out which methods cause network packets to be sent out to the server. I could just log all method calls and figure out what is what by comparing timings in network monitor and method calls dumps. But I don't know how to do the method call logging.

The only way to log anything I could find assumes the availability of source code and requires including logging libraries and marking the interesting objects accordingly. *But I don't have the source code*, only the application build to work with.

How do I log method calls with parameter values in a .net application build?

Comment: Why do you need method names if you have no source code?

Comment: So that I could call them in the app's libraries directly.